# Codeigniter Ajax Crud using DataTables - Insert _ Add Data

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

There is this codeigniter tutorial from weblesson youtube page About working with Datatables and Codeigniter.

But i'm having some difficulties inserting data into the database.

Controller:

```
function user_action(){  
       if($_POST["action"] == "Add")  
       {  
            $insert_data = array(  
                 'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),  
                 'last_name' => $this->input->post("last_name"),  
                 'image' => $this->upload_image()  
            );  
            $this->load->model('crud_model');  
            $this->crud_model->insert_crud($insert_data);  
            echo 'Data Inserted';  
       }  
  }  
  function upload_image()  
  {  
       if(isset($_FILES["user_image"]))  
       {  
            $extension = explode('.', $_FILES['user_image']['name']);  
            $new_name = rand() . '.' . $extension[1];  
            $destination = './upload/' . $new_name;  
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'], $destination);  
            return $new_name;  
       }  
  }
```

View Class:

```
<div id="userModal" class="modal fade">  
  <div class="modal-dialog">  
       <form method="post" id="user_form">  
            <div class="modal-content">  
                 <div class="modal-header">  
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Add User</h4>  
                 </div>  
                 <div class="modal-body">  
                      <label>Enter First Name</label>  
                      <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control" />  
                      <br />  
                      <label>Enter Last Name</label>  
                      <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control" />  
                      <br />  
                      <label>Select User Image</label>  
                      <input type="file" name="user_image" id="user_image" />  
                 </div>  
                 <div class="modal-footer">  
                      <input type="submit" name="action" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" />  
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                 </div>  
            </div>  
       </form>  
  </div>
```

When i ran this code, i got the following errors:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQg7l.png)

And when i did

```
if(isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"] == "Add")
```

i got an empty alert box

Comment: Pleas click on the ERROR MESSAGE link to view the error message

Comment: try below code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller,at your constructor load `url` helper. and save file as `Main.php` with code::

```
function __construct()
  {
    $this->load->helper('url');
  }
  function user_action(){  
       if($_POST["action"] == "Add")  
       {  
            $insert_data = array(  
                 'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),  
                 'last_name' => $this->input->post("last_name"),  
                 'image' => $this->upload_image() 
            );  
            $this->load->model('crud_model');  
            $this->crud_model->insert_crud($insert_data);  
            echo 'Data Inserted';  
       }  
  }  
  function upload_image()  
  {  
       if(isset($_FILES["user_image"]))  
       {  
            $extension = explode('.', $_FILES['user_image']['name']);  
            $new_name = rand() . '.' . $extension[1];  
            $destination = './upload/' . $new_name;  
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'], $destination);  
            return $new_name;  
       }  
  }
```

at your view define a input of type `hidden` with name action and value add.And define action of your form.As follows..

```
<div id="userModal" class="modal fade">  
  <div class="modal-dialog">  
       <form method="post" id="user_form" action="<?php echo base_url('main/user_action');?>">  
       <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add">
            <div class="modal-content">  
                 <div class="modal-header">  
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Add User</h4>  
                 </div>  
                 <div class="modal-body">  
                      <label>Enter First Name</label>  
                      <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control" />  
                      <br />  
                      <label>Enter Last Name</label>  
                      <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control" />  
                      <br />  
                      <label>Select User Image</label>  
                      <input type="file" name="user_image" id="user_image" />  
                 </div>  
                 <div class="modal-footer">  
                      <input type="submit" name="action" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" />  
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                 </div>  
            </div>  
       </form>  
  </div>
```

Hope it will works..

Comment: i did auto load my url helper class

Comment: i think i've been able to fix it

Comment: if you are getting any error in ajax...post your code i can help.

Answer (score 0):

I did fix the problem but don't know if it's the best way to do it

what i did was change this two codes:

controller:

```
public function user_action(){  
       if(isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"] == "Add")  
       {  
            $insert_data = array(  
                 'first_name'          =>     $this->input->post('first_name'),  
                 'last_name'               =>     $this->input->post("last_name"),  
                 'image'                    =>     $this->upload_image()  
            );  
            $this->load->model('crud_model');  
            $this->crud_model->insert_crud($insert_data);  
            echo 'Data Inserted';  

  }
```

and Ajax:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#user_form', function(event){  
       event.preventDefault();  
       var firstName = $('#first_name').val();  
       var lastName = $('#last_name').val();  
       var extension = $('#user_image').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();  
       if(jQuery.inArray(extension, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1)  
       {  
            alert("Invalid Image File");  
            $('#user_image').val('');  
            return false;  
       }  
       if(firstName != '' && lastName != '')  
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"<?php echo base_url() . 'main/user_action'?>",  
                 method:'POST',  
                 data:new FormData(this),  
                 contentType:false,  
                 processData:false,  
                 success:function(data)  
                 {  
                      alert(data);  
                      $('#user_form')[0].reset();  
                      $('#userModal').modal('hide');  
                      dataTable.ajax.reload();  
                 }  
            });  
       }  
       else  
       {  
            alert("Bother Fields are Required");  
       }  
  });
```

for controller:

where it say:

```
if(isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"] == "Add")
```

remove it

In in the Ajax Code:

create a link variable to get the action attribute of the form like so:

```
var link = $('#user_form').attr('action');
```

and parse it to to the ajax url.

And that's it!

Answer (score 0):

I did fix the problem but don't know if it's the best way to do it

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" class="btn btn-success" value="Add">
  <input type="submit" name="action" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" />  
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

This is a hidden field that we have used to describe database operations like insert, update, delete

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.